# How to access the parameters of a Post request in the onAuthorization method of AuthorizeAttribute in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am looking for a way to be able to access the parameters of a Post request in the OnAuthorize method during customAuthorization.

I have looked at other threads and tried the below ways but that did not work.

In this case the ActionArguments is empty.

```
AgentSummaryParams summary = (AgentSummaryParams)actionContext.ActionArguments["AgentSummaryParams"];
        string userID = (string)actionContext.ActionArguments["UserID"];
```

in the following way the query is empty string.

```
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query);
    var myQueryParam = queryString["MyValue"];
```

I cant find the method GetQueryNameValuePairs() on the request object.

```
 var queryParameters = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

var some_value = queryParameters.ContainsKey("some_key") 
        ? queryParameters["some_key"] : string.Empty;
```

Could somebody please let me know how to be able to access the request parameters of a HttPost method in the following method?

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        ModelParamssummary = (ModelParams)actionContext.ActionArguments["ModelParams"];
        string userID = (string)actionContext.ActionArguments["UserID"];           

    }
}
```

**Answer Updated**

```
    var request = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JObject Obj = JObject.Parse(request);
            UseID = (string)Obj["UserID"];
```

The last two lines lets me just get the exact key value pair I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are saying POST so the data will be post in the body,

You can get the string value and then convert it to your model

```
   var request = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

Use the output string and convert to model

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked !!. I have updated my answer with the full solution you provided.